# Django Multiple Files Upload

Tags: python, django

I would like to upload multiples files in my model in Django. I am struggling on the HTML part. I would like to include it part of my detail view without having to create a special view to upload the files. When I click on the button, it open the file upload, I select them but they don`t seem to be attached to the model. Any ideas please?

[image: Upload Files]

**models.py**

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)    

class Attachment(models.Model):
    quote = models.ForeignKey(Quote, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='quotes/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class AttachmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attachment
        fields = ('file', )
        widgets = {
            'file': ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
        # widget is important to upload multiple files
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")   
def add_attachment(request, quote_id):
    form = AttachmentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    quote = get_object_or_404(Quote, pk=quote_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        quotes_attachments = quote.attachment_set.all()  
        attachment = form.save(commit=False)
        attachment.quote = quote
        attachment.attachments = request.FILES['attachments']
        file_type = attachment.attachments.url.split('.')[-1]
        file_type = file_type.lower()        
        attachment.save()
        return render(request, 'quotes/quote_detail.html', {'quote': quote})
    context = {
        'quote': quote,        
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'quotes/quote_detail.html', context)
```

**quote_detail.html**

```
<div class="card-block">
    <form action="/static/assets/plugins/fileupload/js/file-upload.php" method="post" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
         <div class="fallback">
             <input name="file" type="file" multiple 
              style="display: none;"
              data-url="{% url 'projects:add_attachment' quote.id %}"
              data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
         </div>
    </form>
    <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">                               
       <thead>
          <tr>                                                          
             <th>File Name</th>
             <th>File</th>                          
             <th>Actions</th>                                           
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>                                                      
          <tr>                                                                                  
            <td>{{ quote.attachments.id }}</td>                             
            <td></td>                               
            <td><a target="_blank" href="{{ quote.attachments.url }}"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></td>                                                          
          </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>                                       
</div>
```

**file-upload.php**

```
<?php
$ds= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
}
?>
```